# Link color is not changing in HTML file in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, colors, hyperlink

I made a page which is saved in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4ByF/2/) (original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4ByF/) link).

Here I have set the color of the `link` in case of `link`,`active`,`visited`,`hover`. But after the first time, whenever I load the page in firefox, it always shows the color of `visited` i.e. pink. How can I reset the color as yellow i.e.the `link` color, that is shown the first time?

Also I could not understand how can I check if the blue color i.e. color of `active` is coming or not?

Comment: You mean it shows pink without visiting the link, or it shows pink if you've visited the link and then come *back* (and it's pink)? You may be thinking of `:active`, which only changes to pink when the link has been activated, e.g., after it was clicked.

Comment: Also, the markup in the fiddle is not correct; the `ol` at the bottom is not closed and has invalid markup within it. I imagine you just want to delete it.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217749/resetting-visited-status-on-links

Comment: @JaredFarrish it shows pink if I have visited the link already and when I comeback or reload the page the color remains pink which I want to be yellow.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the visited functionality from the site?

Comment: If you want your link to appear unvisited (but don't want to clear your browser history), just add `#001` to the end of the URL. Click it to test the colors. Then change to `#002` and refresh the page. Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really want is the [`:focus` psuedo-selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus), not the [`:visited` selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-visited), since you don't want a *durable* (i.e., kept per page load) change. You want an *in this instance* change. [`:active`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active) only works *for the duration of a mouse-click on a link*.

See:

```
A:focus {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: pink;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4ByF/3/

And click on the first link. You'll see it take the `:focus` psuedo-selector.

Here the effect is a little easier to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/w4ByF/4/

Comment: Thanks @jared it was of great help!!

Answer (score 3):

You have

`A:visited {text-decoration: none;color: pink;}`

So all of the visited links will be pink. If you want them to reset to yellow, you have to change that line to:

`A:visited {text-decoration: none;color: yellow;}`

Now it will always look like they've visited for the first time with the links.

Here's something I've learned over time: a and a:visited should always be the same; a:hover & a:active should always be the same.

Secondly: You may check your :active color by clicking the link and holding down the mouse button. Mousedown on the link, but don't let go of the button. You'll see it turn to your active color.

Comment: *"Here's something I've learned over time: a and a:visited should always be the same;"* — Why? I never get why people try to strip functionality out of the browser. People like to know if they've visited a page before or not. Arguably, this is more important now that it used to be, as editors have gotten used to writing proper copy and are linking phrases or words to a certain page rather than printing out the target URL in full. Much better to have a separate visited colour than having your users going in circles & very few designs that can't incorporate that if done properly.

Comment: Some people prefer form, others function I suppose. To each his own.